# VS2010 - Adding new projects do not inherit existing build configurations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with many projects and many build configurations in order to make use of Web.config transformations for automatic deployments.

My problem is when a new project is added it does not inherit the existing configurations and thus the build fails on the build server.

As an example, say I have the following custom build configurations:

- Development
- QA
- Production

When a new project is added, it only contains the standard Debug and Release configurations and none of the above custom configs.

The only way I know how to fix it is to manually edit the .csproj file.

What is the proper way to handle this?

**Edit** I have removed the information about why it fails on the build server because that is irrelevant (and obvious), I just need to know if there is a way to have existing custom build configurations automatically picked up by a new project being added to the solution.

Comment: This is a simple education problem.  Probably made worse by the devs not building their projects the same way as the build server, that's never not a mistake.  Bad practices can be hard to eradicate, make sure that build breaks are visible to *everybody*, including the boss.

Comment: My issue has nothing to do with breaking builds, I can personally add a project to my solution right now and it will not contain the custom build configurations that every other project in the solution has. The only way I know to add those custom build configs to the new project is to manually edit the .csproj file, I want to know if there is a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle something you have to do manually on a computer is, usually, doing it automatically. No kidding. All our project files (both C# and C++) are generated: they automatically import the correct property sheets with all build options and all have the same platforms/configurations. It's a relative small amount of work to throw together a program that will save you much more time and effort later on. Basically the [`Microsoft.Build.Construction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction%28v=vs.121%29.aspx) namespace has everything you need. To make the program user-friendly we added a small ui on top that lets you drag in directories in which to create projects. So we just run it, create a directory, drag it onto it and add the new project to the solution in VS.

Comment: While this may work, I'm still wondering if there is an *out-of-the-box* automatic solution rather than a *custom* automatic solution.

Comment: When VS creates a new project it uses a template, and it doesn't care at all which configurations you have in the solution that happens to be currently opened. Afaik that's just how it works and there's no way to let it do what you want out of the box.. So the only other option, again afaik, is changing the default project file templates VS uses. But then you'd have to do that on every develeoppers machine. And whenever you create a project, it would start from the template so you'd always have a bunch of custom build configurations which seems rather unwanted.